# Number theoretic sequences and Hecke eigenvalues

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms

What are some number theoretic sequences that you know of that occur as (or are closely related to) the sequence of Fourier coefficients of some sort of automorphic function/form or the sequence of Hecke eigenvalues attached to a Hecke eigenform?

I know many such sequences, but am always looking for more.

Some examples

(1) The sequence a(n) deriving from the traces a(p) of the Frobenius elements in a Galois representation (Langlands reciprocity conjecture)

(2) Number of representations of a natural number as a sum of k squares (theta functions)

(3) The sum of powers of divisor functions (Eisenstein series)

(4) The central critical values of L-functions attached to all quadratic twists of a Hecke eigenform (Kohnen, Waldspurger)

(5) Intersection numbers of certain subvarieties of Hilbert modular surfaces (Hirzebruch-Zagier)

I'll end with a question that is ill-posed but nevertheless very interesting (at least to me personally): why do so many familiar and yet diverse sequences appear in this fashion? Note that many of them have a history of study that precedes the recognition that they are essentially coefficients of automorphic functions/forms.

Comment: Theta functions aren't restricted to sums of squares.  You can enumerate representations of natural numbers as the output of an arbitrary positive definite quadratic form.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Characters of rational vertex operator algebras tend to yield modular functions.  This is due to the space of torus partition functions in a chiral conformal field theory being a complex moduli invariant.  The standard example is the monster vertex algebra, whose character is j-744.  Other examples come from lattice CFTs (presumably describing a bosonic string propagating in a torus), and have the form of a theta function divided by a power of eta.  The characters are never Hecke eigenforms, because of the pole at infinity, but traces arising from higher-weight vectors may be.  In some cases, the vertex algebra structure is supposed to arise from geometry of a target space, so this phenomenon may be related to Hirzebruch-Zagier (number 5).

Characters of highest weight representations of affine Kac-Moody algebras yield modular forms.  One can reasonably argue that this is a special case of the previous paragraph, since (I think) they come from Wess-Zumino-Witten.  The Weyl-Kac character formula for such representations is one way to get Macdonald identities, and the smallest case (trivial rep of affine sl<sub>2</sub>) yields the Jacobi triple product.

Comment: Since this question was asked such a long time ago i dont really expect an answer but if you find time can you please elaborate on "In some cases, the vertex algebra structure is supposed to arise from geometry of a target space, so this phenomenon may be related to Hirzebruch-Zagier (number 5)" Is there an example of this phenomenon?

Comment: @shehryarsikander This was mostly a reference to the Chiral de Rham complex and Chiral Differential Operators.  I do not know of a specific situation where intersection numbers yield a Hecke eigenform in this context.

Comment: Much thanks! How does one see intersection numbers in the context of Chiral de Rham complex and Chiral Differential Operators, weather or not they are eigenvalues of Hecke operators being a secondary question.

Comment: @shehryarsikander I do not know an immediate answer, but I seem to recall there is an additional differential on the Chiral de Rham complex that yields a quasi-isomorphism with the de Rham complex.

Comment: Thanks again! Is there a reason why the q-expansion of characters of Rational VOAs have integer coeffecients? Perhaps a physical reason?
Also, is it completely hopeless to play this game in genus two and hope that the characters are Siegel modular forms?

Comment: @shehryarsikander For your first question, this is because the q-expansion coefficients are dimensions of vector spaces.  People have tried in genus 2 (see papers of Mason and Tuite) and there seem to be some strange discrepancies.

Comment: Are the characters of Rational VOAs ever cusp forms of weight two? In your answer they are always of weight zero(modular functions). In Hirzebruch-Zagier the intersection numbers correspond to coeffecients of cusp forms of weight two.

Comment: You can form weight 2 modular forms using characters of vectors of weight 2, but I don't know any cuspidality criteria.

Comment: Theorem 1 in Hirzebruch Zagier constructs weight two Eisenstein series and weight two cusp forms with coeffecients which are intersection numbers of T_N with T_0 in first case T_N with a curve orthognal to T_0 in the second case. The level of these functions is the dicriminant of the totally real field defining the hilbert modular surface in which T_N reside. 
If one of these Eisenstein series is the character of a Rational VOA, then indeed one can say that they are arising from the geometry of the moduli space of the target space.

Comment: Namely, the target space is an abelian surface(T^4) such that its endomorphism ring is isomorphic to the ring of integers of a totally real quadratic field K. The moduli space of such surfaces is precisely the hilbert modular surface of K and indeed intersection numbers in this moduli space are coeffecients of the characters
Are there explicit examples of character of Rational VOAs which are Eisenstein series of weight two and level a prime which is congruent to 1 mod 4(This is the condition in HZ)? Then one can try to work out the geometric interpretation in this example.

Answer (score 5):

Another example: various subsequences of the integer partition function p(n) occur as coefficients of (sometimes half-integer weight) modular forms. One reference is Ahlgren and Boylan "Arithmetic properties of the partition function".